# Retrieve All Sub-Accounts of an Account with Javascript

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011, odata, crm

I want to display a low level treeview with all Sub-Accounts of an Account. But I'm not able to retrieve all related Sub-Accounts trough oData of a specific Account.

I tried some suggestions with the OData Query Designer but I always get the message "NotFound". My current query is

```
http://localdev:5555/DynamicsCRM2011/xrmservices/2011/OrganizationData.svc/AccountSet(guid'19F4DA91-B0FD-E111-BAA8-00155D03A50D')/account_parent_account
```

The Relationship is 1:N.

Are there any Suggestion how to solve this?

Comment: Can you rephrase the Question.

Comment: Ok, I found a solution. If you add a Sub-Account to an Account the Parent Account lookup on this account will be filled out with the parent account. Sometimes the answer is simple :)

Answer (score 2):

For get related records you have to use $expand, like that:

```
/AccountSet?$expand=opportunity_customer_accounts
```

See more examples [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309461.aspx#BKMK_expand).

Comment: This is Kind of strange. The example you wrote works like a charm with opportunity_customer_accounts but with account_parent_account pops the same error up "The remote server returned an error: NotFound."